# AVG limited to 3 last values for each group

Tags: mysql

Basically i have two tables:

Here's code to create two tables if this can help someone who will be willing to help me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coefficients` ( 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
    `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `score` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `coefficients` (`id`, `datetime`, `campaign_id`, `score`) VALUES    
    (1, '2017-01-29 22:32:13', 1, 20.00),   
    (2, '2017-01-29 22:36:22', 1, 34.00),   
    (3, '2017-01-29 22:36:30', 1, 30.00),   
    (4, '2017-01-29 22:36:43', 1, 1000.00), 
    (5, '2017-01-29 22:37:13', 2, 10.00),   
    (6, '2017-01-29 22:37:26', 2, 15.00),   
    (7, '2017-01-29 22:37:43', 2, 20.00),   
    (8, '2017-01-29 22:30:51', 2, 1000.00);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statistics` ( 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `stats1` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `stats2` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `statistics` (`id`, `campaign_id`, `stats1`, `stats2`) VALUES   
    (1, 1, 34, 38),
    (2, 2, 23, 45);
```

I would like to get average coefficient for each campaign_id calculated based on latest 3 logged coefficients for each campaign_id.

Here's screenshot of two tables and result that i need to get:

[data + result (visual representation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ZZh.png)

The main problem is that i have no idea how to join these two tables if i need only average coefficient for each campaign_id based on 3 latest logged nu,bers for it :(

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Please accept the edit and add the expected resultset to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give you the top 3 records per `campaign_id` from `coefficients` table:

```
SET @currcount = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;
SELECT id, campaign_id, score, c_index FROM (
  SELECT
  id, campaign_id, score, 
  @currcount := IF(@currvalue = campaign_id, @currcount + 1, 1) AS c_index,
  @currvalue := campaign_id AS s
  FROM coefficients
  order by id
) AS a where c_index <= 3
```

Now, all you have to do is, add a `GROUP BY` to this query, calculate `average` score and join it with `statistics` table, e.g.:

```
SET @currcount = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;
SELECT a.id, a.campaign_id, avg(score), c_index, s.stats1, s.stats2 FROM (
  SELECT
  id, campaign_id, score, 
  @currcount := IF(@currvalue = campaign_id, @currcount + 1, 1) AS c_index,
  @currvalue := campaign_id AS s
  FROM coefficients
  order by id
) AS a join statistics s on a.campaign_id = s.campaign_id
where c_index <= 3
group by campaign_id
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b548f/19/0)**.

Comment: Amazing! It does exactly what i needed! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the best way is usually to use variables.  Getting the statistics is just a `join`, so that is not interesting.  Let's get the average from the `coefficients` table:

```
select c.campaign_id, avg(c.score) as avg_score
from (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = c.campaign_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := c.campaign_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from coefficients c cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params
      order by c.campaign_id, c.datetime desc
     ) c
where rn <= 3
group by c.campaign_id;
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback! Unfortunately it doesnt provide result for each campaign as expected: http://prntscr.com/e1y398

Comment: @AntonHrenov . . . It needed the `group by` (which I just added).